# Что означает доллар?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять, что означает эта запись на `jQuery`:

```
var $tab_title_input = $( "#tab_title"),
```

Насколько я знаю, знак доллара обычно обозначает какую-то функцию (или слово `jQuery`). Что этим хотели сказать разработчики? Пример взят с офсайта `jQuery`.

Comment: такого вопроса не ожидал...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Знак доллара является разрешенным символов для идентификатора в языке Javascript.
- jQuery использует знак $ как псевдоним (сокращение) для идентификтора [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

То есть в данном конкретном случае

- `$tab_title_input` - просто имя, включающее знак доллара,
- `$( "#tab_title")` - вызов функции jQuery.

Comment: Я уже не ожидал тут адекватного ответа. +

Comment: @Sh4dow, извиняюсь за глупый вопрос))

Comment: На самом деле, вопрос достаточно любопытный и ответ на него неочевидный.

Answer (score 5):

Нашел в одной статье, думаю это будет полезно к сведению.

**Венгерская нотация**
([Советы: как писать качественный код на jQuery](http://frontender.info/writing-better-jquery-code/#ispolyzuytevengerskuyunotatsiyu))

Если говорить простыми словами, венгерская нотация1 в jQuery — это когда в начале переменной стоит символ доллара, и вам легко сразу понять, что эта переменная содержит jQuery-объект.

```
// плохо
var first = $('#first');
var second = $('#second');
var value = $first.val();

// хорошо - перед объектами, которые управляются jQuery, мы ставим символ $
var $first = $('#first');
var $second = $('#second'),
var value = $first.val();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
$("mydiv").onclick = function()
{
  //some actions
}
```

К примеру когда я обращаюсь к DOM элементам используя функцию выше, я хочу сказатать что использовать знак $ для меня просто удобно! Я не сторонник Jquery, и свои велосипеды тоже умеют ездить!

Comment: Это не имеет отношения к данному вопросу. Кстати, как к стороннику нэйтива, можно ваш аналог?)

    $('.link span.blick[rel="on"]').fadeIn().fadeOut();

Comment: @Sh4dow blick?) Не все же поймут) Аналог есть всему, понятно что код вырастает в разы. Но мое мнение остается моим, если есть возможность обойтись без Jquery, я обхожусь! И к стате если я написал что не сторонник, это не значит что я его не использую!)

Comment: З.Ы. Я в курсе что отношение не имеет к данному вопросу, пример говорит о том что знак $ как написал @Tool Tip в п.1 может использоваться вообще в javascript!

Answer (score 1):

$ у переменной значит, что это объект jQuery

Comment: У переменной в js это значит, что автор косит под php или хочет показать, что это объект jquery. 

    var $a = 0; // не объект jquery.

Comment: Если у вас есть код как на js так и на jquery, принято переменным добавлять $(я думаю вы это знаете). $el = $('#el') для объекта jquery и el = document.getElementById('el') для остальных. Конечно, если просто написать $a=0, то это просто автору так захотелось и логические причины почему он так назвал переменную ведомы только ему.

Comment: @makregistr, а я так не делаю.

Comment: я тоже это не использую, это просто рекомендации их необязательно выполнять

Comment: @Sh4dow, что означает 

>// не объект jquery.

и где можно подробней о них почитать?

Comment: @alex_90, это то и значит, что от первого $ в начале имени переменной она не становится объектом и вообще ничего не происходит.
В приведённом примере $a - это число.

Answer (score 0):

Инициализация (то бишь она же идентификация, обозначение что это jQuery дабы не вызывать конфликтов)jQuery. 
P.S. Не объект, не закос под пшп, это инициализация!
Так же может использоваться как простой символ в имени переменной, либо как вызов функции.