# Знак доллара перед параметром функции в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Для чего используется знак доллара перед параметром функции в JS?
Пример из easytabs плагина function(event, **$clicked, $targetPanel**, settings):

```
$('#quick-tabs').easytabs({
    tabs: '#quick-tabs-nav > a',
}).bind('easytabs:after', function(event, $clicked, $targetPanel, settings) {
});
```

Comment: Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/84909/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80) описано Рекомендую воспользоваться поиском.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что означает доллар?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/84909/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%80)

Answer (score 1):

Знак $ в jQuery используется  как сокращение для идентификтора jQuery.

Например

- `$i` - просто имя,
- `$( "#tab_title")` - вызов функции JQuery.

Comment: В чем тогда разница передачи
function(event, $clicked, $targetPanel, settings) 
и
function(event, clicked, targetPanel, settings)

Comment: Параметры у функции будут называться по разному

Comment: @user404677, нет разницы, параметры можно как угодно называть, главное чтобы название было валидным js идентификатором