# Что значит доллар в этом выражении?

Tags: javascript

Я изучаю js и часто натыкаюсь на синтаксис `$.метод`, и не понимаю что за доллар. Не могу найти информацию про этот доллар.

Вот пример использования этого доллара:

```
$.on('button', 'click', function onClick() {
    setTimeout(function timer() {
        console.log('You clicked the button!');    
    }, 2000);
});
```

Кусок кода взят из этого [сайта](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=JC5vbignYnV0dG9uJywgJ2NsaWNrJywgZnVuY3Rpb24gb25DbGljaygpIHsKICAgIHNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24gdGltZXIoKSB7CiAgICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ1lvdSBjbGlja2VkIHRoZSBidXR0b24hJyk7ICAgIAogICAgfSwgMjAwMCk7Cn0pOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkhpISIpOwoKc2V0VGltZW91dChmdW5jdGlvbiB0aW1lb3V0KCkgewogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkNsaWNrIHRoZSBidXR0b24hIik7Cn0sIDUwMDApOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIldlbGNvbWUgdG8gbG91cGUuIik7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Формально доллар в js такой же символ, как и буква.

Но в данном случае он - jQuery. Точнее, похож на него, но если чистый jQuery смотреть, то он так не умеет.

Answer (score -1):

Поскольку у нас умеют отвечать люди без порога вхождения, вроде [Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy),
я опишу так:

Есть понятие `лямбда-функций` (просто имя функции в символ, отличный от `/^[0-9a-zA-Z]$/`), а в сути, это просто переменная, названная `$`.

Можно посмотреть какие символы (а также ключевые слова, раз Вы

> ~натыкаетесь

) запрещены в названии переменной и Вы поймёте, что это просто такая функция (неисключительно, но, возможно, что иначе - объект) с названием `$` и методом `.on`.

В общем, ничего особенного.

Скорее всего, раз

> ~натыкались

Вы на сайтах, то это действительно может быть библиотека `jQuery`, как подмечено выше.

Собственно, это непосредственный ответ про `$`, а не 'его' какой-то частный пример.

Comment: Нифига не понятно, но здесь я понял - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/84918/503955. Короче, мне надо изучать jQuery.

Comment: @Egork.vorobiev, jQuery устарел лет 10 назад. Весьма маловероятно, что его надо изучать. Кстати, может это всё-таки не jquey, ну или там какой-то хитрый плагин подключен. Оно как бы похоже, но с документацией не сходится...

Comment: @Qwertiy https://api.jquery.com/on/ вот здесь документация про метод on, но только странно что синтаксис у него немного другой по сравнению с тем, который у меня в вопросе. Либо другая версия jQuery, либо как ты говоришь хитрый плагин подключен.

Comment: @Egork.vorobiev, в курсе, потому сначала и решил, что это он. Но есть нюансы: 1. метод on должен вызываться на обёрнутом в jquery dom-элементе, а не на глобальном $, но тут я допускал, что просто не знаю, что так тоже можно. 2. Селектор и событие стоят в обратном порядке - вот из-за этого я полез проверять и выяснил, что оба пункта в jquery не работаюют.

Comment: @Egork.vorobiev однозначная проверка: `.toString()` и проверка 2 и 3 версии `jQuery`. Можете поискать какой-нибудь онлайн-парсер библиотек. Ленивый поиск дал стрёмные и(ли) trial-варианты (лимитированное количество пользования).